# How can I get my table to display grouped data properly?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, javascript-objects

I thought I fixed this issue earlier but I was wrong.  I have an array of objects that I was able to group with lodash.  I then created a summary table out of it, or so I thought.  My summary table needed to look similar to this

[image]

It's just grouped by 'program' and shows a breakdown of each company within the 'program'.

Unfortunately, the company doesn't show nor is it a break down of each company as shown in the link above.  I believe my buildSummary() method is the problem.  I've been dealing with this the past two days and can't think straight.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    test:'hello',
    myData: myData,
    companiesSummary: {},
    myObjData: ''
  },
  created: function(){
    this.buildSummary();
  },
  methods: {
    groupData: function(d){
      return _.groupBy(d, "program");
    },
    buildSummary: function(){
      this.myObjData = this.groupData(this.myData)
      console.log(this.myObjData);
      for (const company of Object.keys(this.myObjData)) {
        this.companiesSummary[company] = {
          totalCount: 0,
          expectedFunding: 0,
          fundedOnIKNS: 0,
        };

        for (const { TotalCount, expectedFunding, fundedOnIKNS } of this.myObjData[company]) {
            this.companiesSummary[company].totalCount += 1;
            this.companiesSummary[company].expectedFunding += expectedFunding === "Yes";
            this.companiesSummary[company].fundedOnIKNS += fundedOnIKNS === "Yes";
        }
      }     
      console.log(this.companiesSummary)
    }
  }
})
```

Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Here's the [pen](https://codepen.io/isogunro/pen/gOYzOpV?editors=1010)

Just wanted to add that TotalCount should show the number of times a company appears in the group it's in.  PLEASE ignore 'Total Count > 3'.

Comment: can you extract a snippet and post it, no idea how your json looks like

Comment: Just added a pen to the question

Comment: posted an answer let me know if it works

Comment: @joyBlanks apologies for the late response.  I get an undefined  ```{undefined: {...}, __ob__:Observer}```

Comment: Also, "totalCount" should evaluate to the number of times each company appears in its group.  I need to reflect that in my question.  sorry about that

Comment: I fixed the errors by tweaking my actual code.  Everything shows great in console but it's not rendering in my table.  Even when I add ```{{companiesSummary}}``` to the html side nothing shows but it shows in the console.

Comment: It seems fine on the codepen that I provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needed to two level of nesting group `program` then `company` and modify the template a little bit as well, added a property companies in every program

```
<div id="app">
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>Program&nbsp;</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Company</td>
      <td>Expected Fund</td>
      <td>Fund on IKNS</td>
      <td>Total Count</td>
    </tr>
    <template v-for="(value) in companiesSummary">
      <tr style="text-align:left">
        <th colspan="6">{{value.program}}</th>
      </tr>
      <template v-for="(value) in value.companies">
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>{{value.company}}</td>
          <td>{{value.totalCount}}</td>
          <td>{{value.expectedFunding}}</td>
          <td>{{value.fundedOnIKNS}}</td>
        </tr>
      </template>
    </template>
</div>
```

The JS

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    test: 'hello',
    myData: myData,
    companiesSummary: {},
    myObjData: ''
  },
  created: function () {
    this.buildSummary();
  },
  methods: {
    groupData: function (d, mode) {
      return _.groupBy(d, mode);
    },
    buildSummary: function () {
      let programGroup = this.groupData(this.myData, 'program');
      let programCompanyGroup = null;
      let companies = [];
      let summary = {};
      for (const program of Object.keys(programGroup)) {
        programCompanyGroup = this.groupData(programGroup[program], 'company');
        for (const company of Object.keys(programCompanyGroup)) {
          summary = { program, company, totalCount: 0, expectedFunding: 0, fundedOnIKNS: 0 };
          for (const data of programCompanyGroup[company]) {
            summary.totalCount += data.TotalCount;
            summary.expectedFunding += data.expectedFunding === "Yes";
            summary.fundedOnIKNS += data.fundedOnIKNS === "Yes";
          }
          companies.push(summary);
        }
        this.companiesSummary[program] = { companies, program };
        companies = [];
      }
      console.table(this.companiesSummary)
    }
  }
})
```

Updated Pen https://codepen.io/joyblanks/pen/oNvdgqL

Answer (score 1):

You can use [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method to group the data by `program` and `company`.

```js
var myData = [{program: "DARC",company: "company E",TotalCount: 2,expectedFunding: "Yes",fundedOnIKNS: "Yes",billingToIKNS: 95,IKNSSWO: "OVER",AcceptedTotal: 45,VacanRecruiting: 34,FilledDeparting: 23},{program: "BBO",company: "company B",TotalCount: 2,expectedFunding: "Expected",fundedOnIKNS: "Yes",billingToIKNS: "IKNS",IKNSSWO: "OVER",AcceptedTotal: 45,VacanRecruiting: 34,FilledDeparting: 23},{program: "BBRC",company: "company D",TotalCount: 2,expectedFunding: "No",fundedOnIKNS: "Yes",billingToIKNS: "IKNS",IKNSSWO: "OVER",AcceptedTotal: 45,VacanRecruiting: 34,FilledDeparting: 23},{program: "CCTG",company: "company C",TotalCount: 2,expectedFunding: "Yes",fundedOnIKNS: "Yes",billingToIKNS: 95,IKNSSWO: "OVER",AcceptedTotal: 45,VacanRecruiting: 34,FilledDeparting: 23},{program: "C2",company: "company A",TotalCount: 2,expectedFunding: "Yes",fundedOnIKNS: "No",billingToIKNS: 95,IKNSSWO: 23,AcceptedTotal: 45,VacanRecruiting: 34,FilledDeparting: 23},{program: "ERI",company: "company C",TotalCount: 2,expectedFunding: "Yes",fundedOnIKNS: "No",billingToIKNS: 95,IKNSSWO: 23,AcceptedTotal: 45,VacanRecruiting: 34,FilledDeparting: 23},{program: "IIRC",company: "company F",TotalCount: 2,expectedFunding: "Yes",fundedOnIKNS: "No",billingToIKNS: 95,IKNSSWO: 23,AcceptedTotal: 45,VacanRecruiting: 34,FilledDeparting: 23},{program: "BBO",company: "company G",TotalCount: 2,expectedFunding: "Yes",fundedOnIKNS: "Yes",billingToIKNS: 95,IKNSSWO: 23,AcceptedTotal: 45,VacanRecruiting: 34,FilledDeparting: 23},{program: "DARC",company: "company E",TotalCount: 3,expectedFunding: "Yes",fundedOnIKNS: "Yes",billingToIKNS: 95,IKNSSWO: 23,AcceptedTotal: 45,VacanRecruiting: 34,FilledDeparting: 23},{program: "BBO",company: "company B",TotalCount: 3,expectedFunding: "No",fundedOnIKNS: "No",billingToIKNS: 95,IKNSSWO: 23,AcceptedTotal: 45,VacanRecruiting: 34,FilledDeparting: 23},{program: "BBRC",company: "company A",TotalCount: 3,expectedFunding: "No",fundedOnIKNS: "Yes",billingToIKNS: 95,IKNSSWO: "OVER",AcceptedTotal: 45,VacanRecruiting: 34,FilledDeparting: 23},{program: "CCTG",company: "company C",TotalCount: 3,expectedFunding: "Yes",fundedOnIKNS: "No",billingToIKNS: "IKNS",IKNSSWO: "OVER",AcceptedTotal: 45,VacanRecruiting: 34,FilledDeparting: 23},{program: "C2",company: "company A",TotalCount: 1,expectedFunding: "No",fundedOnIKNS: "No",billingToIKNS: "IKNS",IKNSSWO: 23,AcceptedTotal: 45,VacanRecruiting: 34,FilledDeparting: 23},{program: "ERI",company: "company E",TotalCount: 1,expectedFunding: "Expected",fundedOnIKNS: "No",billingToIKNS: 95,IKNSSWO: "OVER",AcceptedTotal: 45,VacanRecruiting: 34,FilledDeparting: 23},{program: "IIRC",company: "company F",TotalCount: 1,expectedFunding: "Yes",fundedOnIKNS: "Yes",billingToIKNS: 95,IKNSSWO: "OVER",AcceptedTotal: 45,VacanRecruiting: 34,FilledDeparting: 23},{program: "BBO",company: "company G",TotalCount: 1,expectedFunding: "No",fundedOnIKNS: "Yes",billingToIKNS: "IKNS",IKNSSWO: "OVER",AcceptedTotal: 45,VacanRecruiting: 34,FilledDeparting: 23},   {program: "DARC",company: "company D",TotalCount: 1,expectedFunding: "No",fundedOnIKNS: "No",billingToIKNS: "IKNS",IKNSSWO: "OVER",AcceptedTotal: 45,VacanRecruiting: 34,FilledDeparting: 23},{program: "BBO",company: "company B",TotalCount: 1,expectedFunding: "No",fundedOnIKNS: "No",billingToIKNS: "IKNS",IKNSSWO: 23,AcceptedTotal: 45,VacanRecruiting: 34,FilledDeparting: 23},{program: "BBRC",company: "company A",TotalCount: 1,expectedFunding: "No",fundedOnIKNS: "Yes",billingToIKNS: 95,IKNSSWO: "OVER",AcceptedTotal: 45,VacanRecruiting: 34,FilledDeparting: 23},{program: "CCTG",company: "company A",TotalCount: 1,expectedFunding: "No",fundedOnIKNS: "Yes",billingToIKNS: 95,IKNSSWO: 23,AcceptedTotal: 45,VacanRecruiting: 34,FilledDeparting: 23},{program: "C2",company: "company D",TotalCount: 1,expectedFunding: "No",fundedOnIKNS: "Yes",billingToIKNS: "IKNS",IKNSSWO: 23,AcceptedTotal: 45,VacanRecruiting: 34,FilledDeparting: 23},{program: "ERI",company: "company C",TotalCount: 3,expectedFunding: "No",fundedOnIKNS: "Yes",billingToIKNS: "IKNS",IKNSSWO: 23,AcceptedTotal: 45,VacanRecruiting: 34,FilledDeparting: 23},{program: "IIRC",company: "company A",TotalCount: 3,expectedFunding: "No",fundedOnIKNS: "No",billingToIKNS: "IKNS",IKNSSWO: 23,AcceptedTotal: 45,VacanRecruiting: 34,FilledDeparting: 23},{program: "BBO",company: "company C",TotalCount: 3,expectedFunding: "Yes",fundedOnIKNS: "No",billingToIKNS: 95,IKNSSWO: 23,AcceptedTotal: 45,VacanRecruiting: 34,FilledDeparting: 23},{program: "ERI",company: "company E",TotalCount: 3,expectedFunding: "Yes",fundedOnIKNS: "No",billingToIKNS: 95,IKNSSWO: "OVER",AcceptedTotal: 45,VacanRecruiting: 34,FilledDeparting: 23},{program: "DARC",company: "company D",TotalCount: 3,expectedFunding: "Yes",fundedOnIKNS: "No",billingToIKNS: 95,IKNSSWO: 23,AcceptedTotal: 45,VacanRecruiting: "RECRUIT",FilledDeparting: 23},{program: "BBO",company: "company B",TotalCount: 5,expectedFunding: "Yes",fundedOnIKNS: "No",billingToIKNS: 95,IKNSSWO: 23,AcceptedTotal: 45,VacanRecruiting: 34,FilledDeparting: 23},{program: "BBRC",company: "company B",TotalCount: 5,expectedFunding: "Yes",fundedOnIKNS: "No",billingToIKNS: 95,IKNSSWO: 23,AcceptedTotal: 45,VacanRecruiting: 34,FilledDeparting: 23},{program: "CCTG",company: "company A",TotalCount: 5,expectedFunding: "Yes",fundedOnIKNS: "No",billingToIKNS: 95,IKNSSWO: 23,AcceptedTotal: 45,VacanRecruiting: 34,FilledDeparting: 23},{program: "C2",company: "company B",TotalCount: 5,expectedFunding: "No",fundedOnIKNS: "No",billingToIKNS: 95,IKNSSWO: 23,AcceptedTotal: 45,VacanRecruiting: "RECRUIT",FilledDeparting: 23},{program: "ERI",company: "company C",TotalCount: 5,expectedFunding: "No",fundedOnIKNS: "Yes",billingToIKNS: 95,IKNSSWO: 23,AcceptedTotal: 45,VacanRecruiting: "RECRUIT",FilledDeparting: 23},{program: "IIRC",company: "company F",TotalCount: 5,expectedFunding: "No",fundedOnIKNS: "Yes",billingToIKNS: 95,IKNSSWO: 23,AcceptedTotal: 45,VacanRecruiting: "RECRUIT",FilledDeparting: 23},{program: "BBO",company: "company G",TotalCount: 5,expectedFunding: "No",fundedOnIKNS: "Yes",billingToIKNS: 95,IKNSSWO: 23,AcceptedTotal: 45,VacanRecruiting: 34,FilledDeparting: 23},{program: "DARC",company: "company D",TotalCount: 2,expectedFunding: "Yes",fundedOnIKNS: "Yes",billingToIKNS: 95,IKNSSWO:  "OVER",AcceptedTotal: 45,VacanRecruiting: "RECRUIT",FilledDeparting: 23},{program: "BBO",company: "company B",TotalCount: 2,expectedFunding: "Yes",fundedOnIKNS: "Yes",billingToIKNS: 95,IKNSSWO: 23,AcceptedTotal: 45,VacanRecruiting: "RECRUIT",FilledDeparting: 23},{program: "BBRC",company: "company C",TotalCount: 2,expectedFunding: "Yes",fundedOnIKNS: "Yes",billingToIKNS: 95,IKNSSWO: 23,AcceptedTotal: 45,VacanRecruiting: 34,FilledDeparting: 23},{program: "CCTG",company: "company B",TotalCount: 2,expectedFunding: "Yes",fundedOnIKNS: 'Yes',billingToIKNS: 95,IKNSSWO: 23,AcceptedTotal: 45,VacanRecruiting: 34,FilledDeparting: 23},{program: "C2",company: "company B",TotalCount: 2,expectedFunding: "No",fundedOnIKNS: "No",billingToIKNS: 95,IKNSSWO:  "OVER",AcceptedTotal: 45,VacanRecruiting: 34,FilledDeparting: 23},{program: "ERI",company: "company E",TotalCount: 1,expectedFunding: "No",fundedOnIKNS: 'Yes',billingToIKNS: 95,IKNSSWO:  "OVER",AcceptedTotal: 45,VacanRecruiting: 34,FilledDeparting: 23},{program: "IIRC",company: "company F",TotalCount: 1,expectedFunding: "Yes",fundedOnIKNS: "No",billingToIKNS: 95,IKNSSWO: "OVER",AcceptedTotal: 45,VacanRecruiting: 34,FilledDeparting: 23},{program: "BBO",company: "company G",TotalCount: 1,expectedFunding: "Yes",fundedOnIKNS: 'Yes',billingToIKNS: 95,IKNSSWO:  "OVER",AcceptedTotal: 45,VacanRecruiting: 34,FilledDeparting: 23},{program: "DARC",company: "company C",TotalCount: 1,expectedFunding: "No",fundedOnIKNS: "No",billingToIKNS: 95,IKNSSWO: 23,AcceptedTotal: 45,VacanRecruiting: 34,FilledDeparting: 23},{program: "BBO",company: "company B",TotalCount: 4,expectedFunding: "Yes",fundedOnIKNS: 'Yes',billingToIKNS: 95,IKNSSWO: 23,AcceptedTotal: 45,VacanRecruiting: 34,FilledDeparting: 23},{program: "BBRC",company: "company C",TotalCount: 4,expectedFunding: "No",fundedOnIKNS: "No",billingToIKNS: 95,IKNSSWO: 23,AcceptedTotal: 45,VacanRecruiting: 34,FilledDeparting: 23},{program: "CCTG",company: "company D",TotalCount: 4,expectedFunding: "Expected",fundedOnIKNS: 'Yes',billingToIKNS: 95,IKNSSWO: 23,AcceptedTotal: 45,VacanRecruiting: 34,FilledDeparting: 23},{program: "C2",company: "company B",TotalCount: 4,expectedFunding: "Yes",fundedOnIKNS: 'Yes',billingToIKNS: 95,IKNSSWO: 23,AcceptedTotal: 45,VacanRecruiting: 34,FilledDeparting: 21},{program: "ERI",company: "company B",TotalCount: 4,expectedFunding: "No",fundedOnIKNS: 'Yes',billingToIKNS: 95,IKNSSWO: 23,AcceptedTotal: 45,VacanRecruiting: 34,FilledDeparting: 23},{program: "IIRC",company: "company A",TotalCount: 4,expectedFunding: "Yes",fundedOnIKNS: "Yes",billingToIKNS: 95,IKNSSWO: 23,AcceptedTotal: 45,VacanRecruiting: "RECRUIT",FilledDeparting: 23},{program: "BBO",company: "company C",TotalCount: 4,expectedFunding: "No",fundedOnIKNS: 'Yes',billingToIKNS: 95,IKNSSWO:  "OVER",AcceptedTotal: 45,VacanRecruiting: "RECRUIT",FilledDeparting: 23},{program: "ERI",company: "company E",TotalCount: 1,expectedFunding: "Expected",fundedOnIKNS: 'Yes',billingToIKNS: 95,IKNSSWO:  "OVER",AcceptedTotal: 45,VacanRecruiting: "RECRUIT",FilledDeparting: 232}];

let result = myData.reduce((arr, currentValue) => {

  let item = arr.find(item =>
    item.program === currentValue.program &&
    item.company === currentValue.company);

  if (item) {
    item.expectedFunding += (currentValue.expectedFunding === "Yes" ? 1 : 0);
    item.fundedOnIKNS += (currentValue.fundedOnIKNS === "Yes" ? 1 : 0);
    item.TotalCount += currentValue.TotalCount;
  } else {
    arr.push({
     "program": currentValue.program,
     "company": currentValue.company,
     "TotalCount": currentValue.TotalCount,
     "expectedFunding": (currentValue.expectedFunding === "Yes" ? 1 : 0),
     "fundedOnIKNS": (currentValue.fundedOnIKNS === "Yes" ? 1 : 0),
    });
  }

  return arr;
}, []);


var summary = result.reduce((obj, currentValue) => {      
  var program = currentValue.program;
  
  if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(program)) {
      obj[program] = [];
  }
  
  delete currentValue.program;
  obj[program].push(currentValue);
  
  return obj;
}, {});


console.log(summary);
```

Comment: thanks for your response.   The total was always the same and I couldn't modify it to get the correct value.  ```"totalCount": currentValue.TotalCount,```  "totalCount" should evaluate to the number of times company appears in its group."

Comment: @OLA - I edited the answer to update `totalCount`. Check it out.

Comment: Thanks for you help.